# List of buttons and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a list of buttons in HTML. Depending on the button which is clicked, an AJAX call is supposed to be made and the data displayed. However JavaScript is not able to read the button. Here is the code in HTML

```
<ul>
        <li><input type = "button" name = "lab" id = "map" value = "Computer Lab" onClick = "openPage(this)"></li>

        <li><input type = "button" name = "lib" id = "map" value = "Library" onClick = "openPage(this)"></li>

        <li><input type = "button" name = "mlib" id = "map" value = "Manuscript Library" onClick = "openPage(this)"></li>

        <li><input type = "button" name = "radio" id = "map" value = "Agra ki Aawaz" onClick = "openPage(this)"></li>
      </ul>
```

And here is the javascript code

```
function openPage(page){
try {
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest ();
}
catch (e) {
    try {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject ("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch (el) {
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject ("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (el1) {
            alert ("Your browser does not support AJAX! Please use a compatible browser!!");
        }
    }
}

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.state == 200) {
        var sp = documet.getElementByID ("mainText");
        sp.innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
};

var target = "";
var parent = "";
var page = "";

switch(page.name){
case 'lab':
    target = "get_content.jsp";
    parent = "kmi";
    page = "lab";
    break;
case 'lib':
    targt = "get_content.jsp";
    parent = "kmi";
    page= "gen_lib";
    break;
case 'mlib':
    targt = "get_content.jsp";
    parent = "kmi";
    page= "man_lib";
    break;
case 'radio':
    targt = "get_content.jsp";
    parent = "kmi";
    page= "radio";
    break;
}
xmlHttp.open("POST", target, false);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;");
xmlHttp.send("parent=" + parent + "&page=" + page);
```

Now the problem is that `page.name` is coming as `undefined`.

I don't understand what is wrong with it and is it possible to create such a list of buttons and navigate using these?

Comment: `var page = ""`

Now page is an empty string with no `name` attribute. Calling `page.name` will return `undefined`.

Comment: check with `targt` to `target` in `switch` case

Comment: Both previous comments plus you are probably missing a `}` at the end of your function, but could be a result a wrong copy-paste...

Comment: **id** must be unique for DOM. You're using multiple **id** s which have same values **map** . Instead of **id** you can use **class**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just above your `switch` statement, you have this:

```
var page = "";
```

since your function definition looks like this:

```
function openPage(page){
```

JavaScript drops the `var` (variable is declared already), and merely assigns `""` (an empty string) to what used to be a reference to a DOM element. Fix the name conflict and you should be on your way

Comment: That was really lame. Thanks a lot Ellas!

Comment: @ritesh: We've all been there... Have a cup of coffee and things will sort themselves out :)